# Adding / removing objects in an array based on button click with Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a simple "to-do-list" that I am trying to create that will display a to-do (an object with 4 properties) in a list (an array of objects). I am initializing the list with two to-dos already, and I want the ability to remove a to-do from the list with a button click (the button is held inside the "to-do" component).

Here is the component that creates a single to-do and includes the button for removing it from the list.

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import "./app.css";
import { remove } from "./redux/ducks/listDuck";

const Listitem = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const handleRemove = (id) => {
        dispatch(remove(id));
    };

    return (
        <div className="listitem">
            <div className="listItemHeader">{`${props.title}`}</div>
            <div className="listItemParameters">
                <p>{`Assigned to: ${props.assignedTo}`}</p>
                <p>{`Due date: ${props.dueDate}`}</p>
            </div>
            <button
                id={props.id}
                type="submit"
                className="removeButton"
                onClick={handleRemove}
            >
                Remove
            </button>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Listitem;
```

I am using the "ducks" method for Redux and below is my state, actions, and reducer:

```
// State
const initialState = {
    toDoListArray: [
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "get groceries",
            assignedTo: "bob",
            dueDate: "05/14/2021",
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "haircut",
            assignedTo: "tony",
            dueDate: "05/20/2021",
        },
    ],
};

// Add To-Do Action
const ADDtoLIST = "add-to-list";
export const add = (text) => {
    return {
        type: ADDtoLIST,
        text,
    };
};

// Remove To-Do Action
const REMOVEfromLIST = "remove-from-list";
export const remove = (id) => {
    return {
        type: REMOVEfromLIST,
        id,
    };
};

// Reducer
const items = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADDtoLIST:
            console.log("add");
            console.log(action);
            return {
                ...state,
                toDoListAray: state.toDoListArray.push({
                    id: 5,
                    title: "new to do",
                    assignedTo: "john",
                    dueDate: "today",
                }),
            };
        case REMOVEfromLIST:
            console.log("remove");
            console.log(action);
            return {
                ...state,
                toDoListArray: state.toDoListArray.filter((x) => x.id !== action.id),
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default items;
```

I believe I have set up Redux appropriately because I am able to delete a to-do from the list by specifying an id in the `REMOVEfromLIST` case return; however, my problem is that I am unable to figure out how to delete the specific to-do that the user clicked on. In the code above I am using `action.id` because that was a solution I saw elsewhere, but it doesn't actually delete anything.

I am sure that I am missing something obvious, but I am a beginner and can't seem to figure it out. Any help / suggestions would be welcomed!

I have also put all the code in this CodeSandbox if helpful: https://codesandbox.io/s/to-do-list-o1s0h?file=/src/redux/ducks/listDuck.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the `id` into the component like:

```
<Listitem
      key={x.id}
      id={x.id}
```

Which enables you to do:

```
dispatch(remove(props.id));
```

[image: Edit to-do-list (forked)]

Comment: Thanks T J! That worked - I really appreciate the help. Kicking myself now for not figuring that out.....

Comment: @manderson6361999 it’s not very obvious, “key” is special attribute, it doesn’t get passed in as props like the rest...